# How to return one column dataframe or single row dataframe as a dataframe or a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Give df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(6), 'col2':[*'abcdef']})

   col1 col2
0     0    a
1     1    b
2     2    c
3     3    d
4     4    e
5     5    f
```

Then when selecting a single column, using:

```
df['col1']
# returns a pd.Series

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

Likewise when selecting a single row,

```
df.loc[0]
# returns a pd.Series

col1    0
col2    a
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

How can we force a single column or single row selection to return pd.DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Getting a single row or column as a pd.DataFrame or a pd.Series

There are times you need to pass a dataframe column or a dataframe row as a series and other times you'd like to view that row or column as a dataframe. I am going to show you a few tricks using square brackets, [], and double square brackets, [[]], along with reindex and squeeze.

```
df[['col1']]
# Using double square brackets returns a pd.DataFrame

   col1
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5

# Also using pd.DataFrame.reindex we can returns a single column dataframe
df.reindex(['col1'], axis=1)
```

Now, lets go the other way from the output:

```
# Let's squeeze to get pd.Series from this dataframe
df.reindex(['col1'], axis=1).squeeze()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

And, likewise with rows:

```
df.loc[[0]]
# Using double square brackets returns a single row dataframe

   col1 col2
0     0    a

# Also using reindex
df.reindex([0])
```

Let's squeeze to get pd.Series from this dataframe

```
df.reindex([0]).squeeze()

col1    0
col2    a
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The advantages or using `pd.DataFrame.reindex` over `pd.DataFrame.loc` is handling columns or indexes that may or may not be present in your dataframe. Using .loc, you will get a KeyError if the column is not present. However, using reindex, you will not get an Error you results will be all NaN allowing the code to continue executing.

Using `pd.DataFrame.squeeze` allows you to convert that single column dataframe to a pd.Series without typing in the column header.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `to_frame`:

```
# One column
>>> df['col1'].to_frame()
   col1
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5

# One row
>>> df.loc[0].to_frame().T
  col1 col2
0    0    a
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct but it is a possible alternative for those who are not comfortable with indexing.